# Including FreeType font support in project

Tags: c++, freetype

Sorry if this has already been asked, but I'm making a program on linux with C++/linux and I want to use FreeType to draw text on the screen.  Once I'm done I will need to distribute this program.  What's the best way to do that with FreeType?

- make a script that downloads/compiles/installs freetype?
- Can I somehow statically link it to my program?

Thanks!

Comment: If you distribute the program via a package distribution system (deb, rpm, self-executing archive installer), then you can either link your program to depend on an existing freetype package or include it (if license permits), either in compiled form for a certain architecture or as source for the user to compile on their own. Usually this is done through Makefiles. We need more information in order to answer the question, if you haven't decided that yet you will need to.

Answer (score 0):

Download the library from [here](http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/freetype/) Use [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348127/freetype-how-to-rasterize-non-filled-outline/19949691#19949691) to extract border points from freeType glyph and draw the same using any graphics library X11/GDI to draw it on surface and yes you can statically link it with your program.